# Merge Two Scala Lists of Same Length, With Elements At Same Index Becoming One Element

Tags: scala, list, merge

I have two Scala lists with the same number and type of elements, like so:

```
val x = List("a", "b", "c")
val y = List("1", "2", "3")
```

The result I want is as follows:

```
List("a1", "b2", "c3")
```

How can this be done in Scala? I could figure this out using mutable structures but I think that would be unidiomatic for Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine `zip` and `map`:

```
x zip y map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```

---

Strangely enough, this also works:

```
x zip y map (_.productIterator.mkString)
```

but I would strongly prefer the first version.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had figured out the zipping part but didn't think to map it to a pattern match. You've added to my toolbox. :)